# Why curl > /dev/null and curl -o /dev/null has a large performance difference?

Tags: bash, pipe, curl

I am using Intel Atom D525, an extremely unpowerful processor for my family router with Debian 9. I tried both `curl http://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/sailfish-pq2a.190205.003-factory-164a7269.zip > dev/null` and `curl http://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/sailfish-pq2a.190205.003-factory-164a7269.zip -o dev/null` on that. The previous one can only get a speed of 25 MB/s and the next one can get a speed of 38 MB/s, mostly full of my 300Mbps bandwidth. Why these two command have such a gap of performance?

Comment: I'm commenting rather than answering because this is pure hypothesis, but I suspect that _explicitly telling `curl` via `-o /dev/null`_ behaves more efficiently under-the-hood rather than having the _shell_ redirect the output of `curl` "by hand" into `/dev/null`.  In the first case, `curl`'s output is explicitly sent to null, while in the second, curl writes to stdout, and that is redirected externally from `curl`.

Comment: I do wonder a bit about the use-case here. Are you just measuring your network connection speed? Otherwise one would assume that it would be more interesting to look at how quickly you can download _and_ process/store the file, than just download and throw away.

Comment: @ilkkachu If I use wget, the speed is about 8 MB/s. With curl >, the speed is about 11 MB/s. With curl -o, the speed is about 14 MB/s.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce this.

For that particular file, I did get slower speeds on some of the attempts, but that had nothing to do with the arguments to `curl`, it happened randomly and with both variants.

The version of `curl` I have (`curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, from Debian), also doesn't handle `/dev/null` any differently from other output files, `strace` shows an `open()` and `write()`s to it:

```
$ strace -etrace=open,write curl -s http://www.google.com/ -o /dev/null
[...]
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 4
write(4, "<!doctype html><html itemscope=\""..., 4096) = 4096
write(4, "px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{f"..., 4096) = 4096
...
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Here's an output for my last two runs, no significant difference between the `> /dev/null` and `-o /dev/null`:

```
$ curl http://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/sailfish-pq2a.190205.003-factory-164a7269.zip > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1344M  100 1344M    0     0  94.5M      0  0:00:14  0:00:14 --:--:-- 91.0M

$ curl http://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/sailfish-pq2a.190205.003-factory-164a7269.zip -o /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1344M  100 1344M    0     0  89.3M      0  0:00:15  0:00:15 --:--:-- 92.8M
```

Comment: There are also no differences for the two commands on my PC with Intel i7. But on devices with much slower CPU I can always reproduce this.